# Angularjs : How to show contents of ng-repeat, when using Laravel?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

What I've been trying to do is to show the contents of ng-repeat. The problem is that I can't use the double curly braces, `{{ value }}`.

In case you haven't tried this, let me explain that this expression, `{{ value }}`, is going to find a variable named `$value` if you use Laravel 5.2. Apparently, using double curly braces, `{{ value }}`, won't refer to the content of `ng-repeat`, even if there is an expression like the following one.

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in values"></tr>
```

So, I usually rely on `ng-bind`, but `ng-bind` doesn't seem to work with `ng-repeat` as it usually does.

My code looks like this.

```
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="TableController as tc">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchBox">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchBox">
        {{ student.name }}//This causes an error, indicating "Use of undefined constant student"
            <td ng-bind="student.student_id"></td>
            <td ng-bind="student.name"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('angularApp')
    .controller('TableController', function(){
        this.data = {
            students: [
            @foreach($students as $student)
            "{{ $student }}",
            @endforeach
            ]
        };
    });
</script>
```

`$students` is an array, containing SQL objects called `student`. This comes from a Laravel's controller function.

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong? Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: You need to change the delimiter of angular JS

Answer (score 2):

In your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('angularApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
   $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
angular.controller('TableController', function(){
    this.data = {
        students: $students
    };
});
```

In your blade:

Change `{{ student.name }}` to `[[ student.name ]]`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sadly, however, the `<td>[[ student.student_id ]]</td>` part doesn't appear. This part can be seen on the page source, though. Apparently `<tr ng-repeat="student in students">` tag itself is not working.

Comment: is the script on your blade? try `{!! $student !!}`

Comment: Yes. All of the coding is on the same `blade.php` file.

Comment: try to `console.log("$students")`

Comment: is `$students` a json file?

Comment: `$students` is an array. Each of its contents, `$student`, is a php std object, so it's almost like a json object.

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(this.data)`?

Comment: It says that `Cannot read property 'sts' of undefined`, if I use `console.log(this.data.sts);`. If I use `console.log(this.data);`, nothing appears in the console log.

Comment: What is `sts` in your console.log()?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's actually `this.data. students`! I renamed it for a moment just for testing something

Comment: Apparently, `this.data.students` is not processed as a property, or there is something wrong with how I access this property

Comment: Can i see the structure of `$students`?

Comment: `["{"id":1,"student_id":"fba545","name":"Lolita"}","{"id":2,"student_id":"fd1585","name":"Shad"}",];`

Comment: In your blade. Can you see that structure when you do `[[ data.students ]]`?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I needed to write `<tr ng-repeat="student in tc.data.students">`, since I'm using the `as` syntax for controllers

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems that I had to precede the data name with tc, since I use the as syntax for controllers. I re-posted this question for the sake of simplicity, and will delete this post soon. Again, thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an @ before it

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data

> Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a
>   given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the @
>   symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should
>   remain untouched. For example:
>
> ## Laravel
>
> Hello, @{{ name }}.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. `{{student.student_id }}` can be seen. However, it doesn't reflect the variable. This means that I see `{{student.student_id }}` expression on the screen, instead of the value of `{{student.student_id }}`.

Comment: Did you change the symbol back to {{}} from aldrin27 suggestion.

Comment: I changed the symbol from `{{ }}` to `[[ ]]` before I tried aldrin27's suggestion. After that, I changed back the symbols from `[[ ]]` to `{{ }}`. Then, I tried your suggestion.

Comment: Try changing the  "{{ $student }}" in students array to {{ $student->toArray() }} and  {{ student.name }} to @{{ student.name }}

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I sincerely appreciate your help. Unfortunately, this caused another error, `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. Actually `{{ $student }}` is fine. When I try Laravel's `@foreach` with `{{$student}}`, the contents of each `$student` can be rendered properly.

Comment: Whoops I meant {{ $student->toJson() }}.

Comment: I'm afraid this wasn't a solution either. It seems that `this.data.students` is not properly accessed. Using `console.log(this.data.students)` shows that `this.data.students` is not defined as a property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106313/discussion-between-ymd-and-alan-perez).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems that I had to precede the data name with `tc`, since I use the `as` syntax for controllers. I re-posted this question for the sake of simplicity, and will delete this post soon. Again, thank you so much for your help!!